# How to get the time when a block is received at a node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, block, timestamp, p2p

Is there any variable in the bitcoind code that records the timestamp when a block is received for the first time by a particular node? To be more precise, for transactions, transaction information returned by Bitcoind JSON RPC API contains `timereceived`. Is there similar field for blocks in the API?

There happens to be similar existing questions in stackexchange but none of them has been appropriately answered.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is exposed via the JSON-RPC API.

The easiest method would likely be to have a program monitoring `debug.log` and look for the best height update messages - they will be a few milliseconds off, since I believe those are only logged after block validation has succeeded, but it is likely the closest you can get to a per-node block receipt time, at least without monitoring the network traffic.

Comment: Thanks. In that last line you mention "without monitoring the network traffic". It would be great if you could elaborate on how to determine the timestamps when a block is received by monitoring the network traffic.